# Argument of type is incompatible with other parameter in my program

Tags: c, arrays, math, matrix

I have a C program which read a matrix then in a new array put the maximum of North, South, East, West. I'm trying to make a function to return the array and then write to a file.

I get this error in my VS compiler

> argument of type "int **" is incompatible with parameter of type "int (*)[1000]' (line 80 -   a = functie(matrix, n, m, i, j);)

and I can't figure it out what's the problem. The problem must be created using a return function for maximum elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


int * functie(int matrix[1000][1000], int n, int m, int i, int j)
{

    int index, jindex;
    int *p;
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        p[i] = 0;
    }

    for (index = 0; index < n; index++)
    {
        for (jindex = 0; jindex < m; jindex++)
        {
            if (index < i)
            {
                if (matrix[index][jindex] > p[0])
                    p[0] = matrix[index][jindex];
            }


            if (index > i)
            {
                if (matrix[index][jindex] > p[1])
                    p[1] = matrix[index][jindex];
            }


            if (jindex < j)
            {
                if (matrix[index][jindex] > p[2])
                    p[2] = matrix[index][jindex];
            }


            if (jindex > j)
            {
                if (matrix[index][jindex] > p[3])
                    p[3] = matrix[index][jindex];
            }
        }
    }

    return p;
}

void main()
{
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int **matrix;
    matrix = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*m);

    printf("Citire matrice\n");

    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++)
    {
        for (int jindex = 0; jindex < m; jindex++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[index][jindex]);
        }
    }

    int i, j;
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);

    int *a;
    a = functie(matrix, n, m, i, j);

    FILE *f;
    char output[] = "vector.txt";
    f = fopen(output, "w");
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
    {
        fprintf(f, "%d\n", *(p + i));
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: The variable `int **matrix` is incompatible with the parameter `int matrix[1000][1000]`. You need to change one or both of them. Given that you're hard-coding your dimensions, I suggest you use a 2D array: `int matrix[1000,1000]`. This would require you to change your array accesses to `matrix[i, j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is jagged array that you are forming by allocating memory using `malloc`. It is not the 2d array as you think it is. So how should you pass the parameter?

It would be  (the correct way to pass the `int**`)

```
int * functie(int** matrix, int n, int m, int i, int j){
...
}
```

You might think from where do the weird looking `int (*)[1000]` is coming from? The term insider the first bracket `[1000]` is ignored by the compiler and it is basically considered as an pointer to an array of `1000` `int` elements.(when you pass 2d array as argument to a function - it is converted into pointer to the first element - here first element for 2d array is an 1d array - pointer to that is being considered).

There are few other problems that one can see while skimming through the code - you don't need to cast the return value if `malloc`.
Secondly, `malloc` might not be able to service the request, it might return a null pointer. It is important to
check for this to prevent later attempts to dereference the null pointer. Also check the return value of `scanf`,`fopen` etc.

Comment: No, the matrix is allocated in main then just want to using in the function and in the function i allocate a new array named P where I will remember the maximum elements.

Comment: @dxerok.: Yes then you pass it like that - why would you pass it as if you are passing a 2d array?

Comment: Oh sorry i don't read very well your answer. But if i don't use that [1000][1000] i get 'expression must have pointer-to-object type' on every if.

Comment: @dxerok.: No it doesn;t...check it.

Comment: @dxerok.: You still stuck in the problem?

Comment: Resolved with **matrix in instead of matrix[1000][1000]. Really thank you.